# NGinX and VHost config running into could not find named location "@handler" error

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I see several times this error `could not find named location "@handler"` in my VHost error log.

```
    server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name www.domain.at;
        root /var/www/domain.com/www.domain.com;

        location / {
                index index.html index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
                expires 30d;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_error.log;

        location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

        location /var/export/ {
                auth_basic           "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
                autoindex            on;
        }

        location  /. {
                return 404;
        }

        location  /. {
                return 404;
        }

        location ~ .php/ {
                rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

        location /lib/minify/ {
                allow all;
        }

        location ^~ /blog   { allow all; }

        location ~ .php$ {
                if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
                expires        off;
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}


uname -a  
Linux r3cwzg4q 2.6.32-042stab104.1 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 12:58:41 MSK 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

php -v
PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 

ps aux | grep php
www-data   784  0.5  2.0 515804 107228 ?       S    Nov21  79:16 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data   943  0.5  2.4 801532 130400 ?       Sl   Nov21  79:15 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
root      2258  0.0  0.0 471400  4960 ?        Ss   Okt31   1:36 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
root      8063  0.0  0.0  14136  1048 pts/0    S+   12:57   0:00 grep php
www-data 14918  1.2  2.6 542560 136828 ?       S    Nov29  12:13 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 14919  1.2  2.0 514080 105720 ?       S    Nov29  12:22 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 18119  0.8  2.0 514044 105228 ?       S    Nov28  19:34 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 21371  0.5  5.5 699180 291196 ?       S    Nov19  84:26 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 21430  0.8  1.8 506684 98252 ?        S    Nov29  19:12 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 23462  1.1  1.8 506340 98560 ?        S    01:06   8:02 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 23477  1.1  1.6 502256 86356 ?        S    01:08   8:14 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 23478  1.1  5.3 692924 282608 ?       S    01:08   8:06 php-fpm: pool www    

netstat -lpnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17462           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      263/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1113/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6646/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25740/amavisd-new (
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      861/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1113/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      265/memcached   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6646/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1113/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::17462                :::*                    LISTEN      263/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1113/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10024               :::*                    LISTEN      25740/amavisd-new (
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1113/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      275/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      1113/master
```

That can only come from try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ?
And what's wrong about that?

Comment: You haven't got a `location @handler`!

Comment: Oh .. I had this, but it was commented out: 
`location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler`
`rewrite / /index.php;`
`}`
I'll reactivate it and see whether it's getting better.

Comment: Maybe not. The nginx config shown on the Magento wiki is terrible (for other reasons too) and you shouldn't use it. A much better set of nginx configs can be found at https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config

Comment: Yes - I used parts from there.
I'll double check it and see how to put it together with my environment.